Still impossible to have infinite mirror reflections in Eevee Next?
I can see a bunch of posts about EEVEE legacy, but none about EEVEE Next. I tried all settings I could think of, but it seems that infinite mirrors are still impossible in EEVEE Next. Confirm?
Edit:
Ok, assuming it is impossible, what would be a clever trick to get it working?
First that came to mind - probably not very sophisticated - would be to create duplicate instances of the scenario for the first reflection, then use low poly and low res proxies for the other 3 or 4, decreasing opacity gradually. Even real infinite mirrors seem to kind of fade away after a few reflections. Of course won't work for complex scenes, but for those with a few objects might be good enough of a trade off.


Well technically it is impossible to have "infinite mirrors" regardless of engine, even Cycles has limits to how many iterations it can make. I wouldn't expect any current rasterizer to overcome that limitation any time soon
